# Swift - Custom TableView Not Executing Click on UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift

I am trying to do what I believed was a simple task using Swift. I have created a Custom TableView Cell and added a button to it. I want to be able to just see when you click on the button some action take place. Unfortunately, when I click on the button there is nothing happening. Can someone shed some light on this? I have placed the code below:

Custom TableView Cell:

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var testBtn: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
func buttonTappedOnCell()
{
    println("buttonTapped!")
}

}
```

Below is the code  in the View Controller which the call is being made:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"TestTableViewCell", bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"TestButtonCell")
 let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TestTableViewCell

           cell.testBtn.addTarget(cell, action: "buttonTappedOnCell", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        return cell
}
```

I also tried changing the call to include the ':' -> cell.testBtn.addTarget(cell, action: "buttonTappedOnCell:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown) but this did not work. Another thing I tried is moving the call function into the view controller and having the target action point to self. This unfortunately did not work either. A quick example of this working would be great. At the end of day would like to be able to have a custom table view cell that contains 6 radio buttons allowing the user to select just one. But baby steps first at this point. Thanks for any help.

Comment: At a minimum, I'd move the `.addTarget(...` into the cell subclass. You don't need to re-assign the button's target each time you dequeue it. So, instead, in `awakeFromNib`, do something like: `testBtn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTappedOnCell", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)`

Comment: In addition, `registerNib` really only needs to be once per `UITableViewController` lifetime, move it into `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Just checking the basics: are you sure you have set up your `IBOutlet` to the cell's button correctly? If it's `nil`, it could be the reason it's not forwarding its touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the event you specified in the code.

```
 cell.testBtn.addTarget(cell, action: "buttonTappedOnCell", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
```

Change that `ToouchDown` to `TouchUpInside`

```
cell.testBtn.addTarget(cell, action: "buttonTappedOnCell", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Also why are you setting it programmaticaly ? From your code I think you have the button on your storyboard. So why should you add the IBAction programmaticaly ? (Since the action is also invoked on the same class).

Declare your `buttonTappedOnCell` as an IBAction and connect it directly to your button on storyboard/xib.

Comment: I agree with changing to this event, but why do you think that would have caused the action method not to fire?

Comment: @mbm29414 There could be several reasons. 1) Due to the wrong event subscribed (as in my answer) 2) User Interaction may be false etc

Comment: Yes, but `TouchDown` will **ALWAYS** fire before `TouchUpInside` (i.e., you can't get a `TouchUpInside` without first getting a `TouchDown`), whereas `TouchUpInside` may not fire based on user interaction. I agree with **using** `TouchUpInside`, but I can't see how it will fix the problem the OP is having.

Comment: I actually had the TouchUpInside even previously but changed it to use TouchDown for testing. I changed back but still have the same issue.

Comment: I have UserInteraction checked in IB for the button and the cell as well.

Comment: @doubleace3: is your button enabled and user interaction is set to true ? Also why are you setting it programmaticaly ? From your code I think you have the button on your storyboard. So why should you add the IBAction programmaticaly ? (Since the action is also invoked on the same class)

Comment: As an even better solution, set up the target action in the storyboard itself.  Control-drag from the button to the cell and then select your function.  You'll probably need to add the `@IBAction` tag to your function declaration first.

Comment: @doubleace3: if you have the issue still, can you post an image of your cell design ?

Comment: Yes button is enabled and user interaction was set to true. I had tried the method you asked previously as well but to no success. I must be missing something somewhere. Below is a snapshot of the tableview cell in IB:

Comment: @doubleace3: I didn't see any link to your snapshot

Comment: I can't add the image right now but I have attached the code with the action code into my tableview Cell:

Comment: `import UIKit

     class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        IBOutlet weak var testBtn: UIButton!
      override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
//    func buttonTappedOnCell()
//    {
//        println("buttonTapped!")
//    }

     IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("button clicked!")
    }
    }`

Comment: here is the link to the image of the tableCell in IB: https://letscrate.com/f/doubleace3/misc/tableViewCell.png

Comment: @doubleace3: Your design seems fine, so the connected IBAction is not also working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70820/discussion-between-doubleace3-and-midhun-mp).