# Button Click inside TableView Header is ignore in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, uibutton, dialogviewcontroller

I am making TableView with the custom Header. in the custom header I have 1 ImageView, 2 UILabel and 1 UIButton. When i set TouchUpInSide event on the UIButton it will not fire.

I see many post on the SO and google but nothing is getting help me.

Here What i have tried :

1). [Swift - Custom TableView Not Executing Click on UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486963/swift-custom-tableview-not-executing-click-on-uibutton)

2). [UIButton in UITableView tableHeaderView not responding to touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380732/uibutton-in-uitableview-tableheaderview-not-responding-to-touches)

3). [UIButton in a UITableView header ignores most touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297297/uibutton-in-a-uitableview-header-ignores-most-touches)

Here is my code for Custom header.

**Code :**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            TableView.Frame = new RectangleF((float)TableView.Frame.Left, 130, (float)TableView.Frame.Width, (float)(View.Frame.Size.Height - 130));
            headerView = new UIView();
            headerView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, TableView.Frame.Width, 140);

            UIImageView backgroundImage = new UIImageView();
            backgroundImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile("drawerbg");
            backgroundImage.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, TableView.Frame.Width, 140);
            headerView.AddSubview(backgroundImage);

            profileImage = new UIImageView();
            profileImage.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 70, 70);
            profileImage.Layer.CornerRadius = 35;
            profileImage.ClipsToBounds = true;
            profileImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("default_user");
            backgroundImage.AddSubview(profileImage);

            userName = new UILabel();
            userName.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 90, TableView.Frame.Width - 20, 20);
            userName.Font = GargiFontAndSize.B14();
            userName.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            backgroundImage.AddSubview(userName);

            userOrganization = new UILabel();
            userOrganization.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 110, TableView.Frame.Width - 50, 20);
            userOrganization.Font = GargiFontAndSize.B14();
            userOrganization.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            userOrganization.Text = "Organizaton";
            backgroundImage.AddSubview(userOrganization);

            organizationArrowButton = new UIButton();
            organizationArrowButton.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(260, 110, 20, 20);
            organizationArrowButton.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("sort_down"), UIControlState.Normal);
            organizationArrowButton.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            organizationArrowButton.ClipsToBounds = false;
            backgroundImage.AddSubview(organizationArrowButton);
            organizationArrowButton.BringSubviewToFront(headerView);


            TableView.SectionHeaderHeight = 0;
            TableView.SectionFooterHeight = 0;


            var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradient.Frame = headerView.Frame;
            gradient.Colors = new CoreGraphics.CGColor[] { GargiColor.PrimaryColor().CGColor, GargiColor.SecondaryColor().CGColor };
            headerView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradient, 0);

            TableView.TableHeaderView = headerView;

}
```

One more thing My viewController is extend DialogViewController.

Any Help will be Appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView's userInteraction is disabled by default, and you are adding button to image view, set userInteractionEnabled to true for UIImageView.

Comment: I have also try that in the upper code it is not display because it's only structure.

Comment: as I see in your code, you set userInteractionEnabled for organizationArrowButton, instead or also you need to set it to backgroundImage

Comment: set `backgroundImage.UserInteractionEnabled  = true`.